# CRAFT_WEB_ROOT incorrect when trying to "Move Craft’s Files Below the Webroot"

Tags: assets, config, image-transforms, craft4, server

I'm having trouble deploying a project:

My web hoster automatically generates vhosts for each domain, with their respective webroot being `/var/www/myuser/mydomain.com/`; so I followed the `Moving Craft’s Files Below the Webroot` (https://craftcms.com/knowledge-base/moving-craft-files) approach.

I got everything working so far, except craft now seems to be confused about its `@webroot` path: according to `/admin/utilities/system-report` it is `/var/www/myuser/mydomain.com/app/web` when in fact it should be `/var/www/myuser/mydomain.com`.

I tried explicitly setting `CRAFT_WEB_ROOT="/var/www/myuser/mydomain.com"` in the `.env` file, but it doesn't seem to get picked up (despite `@dotenv` pointing to the correct file).

Additional observations:

- `/admin/assets` sees and lists all the files in `/var/www/myuser/mydomain.com/uploads`

  - new uploads however are saved to `/var/www/myuser/mydomain.com/app/web/uploads`
- `/admin/utilities/asset-indexes` does NOT seem to be aware of the files and warns me about them missing
- on the frontend: all calls to `/actions/assets/generate-transform?transformId=X` fail with a 500 error

Any ideas what the missing piece might be?

Comment: Move to a different web hosting service. Not being able to use a subdirectory as the webroot is a non-starter. It's not worth it to spend time building a worse, insecure setup to accommodate a bad hosting service.